# mpd - pulse and/or alsa problem

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, mpd

**What am I doing?**

I'm trying to get mpd working for the first time so I can stream my audio on multiple Linux devices. My mpd.conf file shows:

```
music_directory     "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/music"
playlist_directory      "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/playlists"
db_file             "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/tag_cache"
log_file            "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/mpd.log"
pid_file            "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/mpd.pid"
state_file          "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/state"
sticker_file                   "/home/john-mcbride/.mpd/sticker.sql"
user                "john-mcbride"
bind_to_address     "any"
input {
        plugin "curl"
}
audio_output {
    type        "alsa"
    name        "My ALSA Device"
}
audio_output {
    type        "pulse"
    name        "My Pulse Output"
    server      "localhost"     # optional
}
```

**What is going wrong?**

When I run ncmpcpp the tracks are stuck on Pause. Here are details from the mpd.log file:

```
Jul 30 19:49 : player: problems opening audio device while playing "Music/Electro/Aphex Twin/AFX/1994 - Analogue Bubblebath (CD EP)/04 A F X 2.mp3"
Jul 30 19:51 : state_file: failed to create /home/john-mcbride/.mpd/state: Permission denied
Jul 30 19:51 : player: played "Music/Electro/Aphex Twin/AFX/1994 - Analogue Bubblebath (CD EP)/04 A F X 2.mp3"
Jul 30 19:51 : avahi: Service 'Music Player' successfully established.
Jul 30 19:51 : alsa_mixer: Failed to read mixer for 'My ALSA Device': no such mixer control: PCM
```

When I comment out the ALSA lines I also get errors for Pulse:

```
Jul 30 19:49 : pulse_output: Failed to open "My Pulse Output" [pulse]: failed to connect: Connection refused
```

So these are my latest in a long list of problems that I've had. Every time I think I have fixed something I get a different error. At the moment it seems to be a mixture of ALSA, Pulse and mpd permissions.

**The question!**

So can you suggest what I should do to get to the point where I can play music with mpd? And can you point out any fundamental problems with the way I am doing this (considering I want to be able to access this on multiple devices)?